# User Control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Can anyone suggest me a link from where I could get all the aspects of user control in asp.net..

Comment: A simple google .NET + User Control should give you the information that you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/default.aspx) is a great resource.

Comment: +1 - because for a crazily generic question like that - there is no better response